# Flutter before killing the app make service call

Tags: flutter, dart, android-lifecycle

Whenever user closing the app abnormally, I have to make a service call to send some data to DB.

I tried using Flutter's life cycle events (detached) with **didChangeAppLifecycleState** override method , most of the times it is getting called(able to see some logs) but I am unable to make service call.

My question is, can we show a confirmation dialog whenever user closing the app from memory(abnormally or wantedly) ,if it is not possible is there any way to make a service call?

Comment: Which is impossible, showing confirmation dialog or making service call? If you have any documents can you please share it?